# Cron is producing duplicate logentrys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

in my code, I try to produce log entries for requests that are controlled by a cronjob. These entries only contain the timestamp of the requests.
Everything in my Code works fine, but when it comes to the second/third/... activation of the function, I get this message in my console:

```
(node:14176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection
```

The second / third ... entry has the same Timestamp of the first entry, but the request is sent 15 Minutes later. Can you help me with this problem? The function that creates and posts the logs in my DB is `createLog()` and works fine...but only for the first run.

Here is the code:

```js
const logger = require('../../logger');                             
const { mapMyWork } = require('./mappings');           
const axios = require('axios');
const job = require('node-cron');
const connectDB = require('./DB');
const { createLog } = require('../someStuff/createLogs');

connectDB;
job.schedule('*/15 * * * *',
doesWhatItShould = async function ( ) {
    createLog();
    const worklogs = await myWhy.getWorklogs({ from: everything, to: worksFine });
    if(!worklogs){
        logger.info('asleep?')
        return false;
    }
    
    const mappedData = mapMyWork(worklogs);

    await myCloud.sendImport(mappedWorklogs);
        
    return true;
   
});

job.start();

module.exports.doesWhatItShould;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, had to create the timestamp in my creatLogs-file in the function to get a new timestamp every turn my cronJob runs.